# Система мультиплеера на PHP

Tags: php

Пишу сайт где пользователи должны отгадывать песни. Игроки заходят в лобби и начинают играть, по окончанию которой они получают опыт. Теперь вопрос, как я могу создать данную систему лобби и мультиплеера?

Я пробовал найти что-то в интернете но практический не ничего нашёл.

В PHP являюсь новичком и могу многого не знать.

Comment: А какой смысл задавать такой вопрос тут? Вы надеетесь, что тут вам напишут полное тех. задание? Вы понимаете какой маштабный вопрос задаёте? Для обучения лучше возмите более простые задания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите писать именно на PHP, то Вам скорее всего пригодятся:

1. **протокол WebSocket** - для постоянного соединения пользователя и сервера. Среди примеров работы этого протокола чаще всего встречаются чат-комнаты - функционал, очень похожий на вашу задачу;
2. **Swoole** или **Ratchet + ReactPHP** - для реализации асинхронного демона, который слушает WebSocket-протокол и исполняет функционал
   ваших комнат на стороне сервера;
3. **Supervisor** - для управления демоном;
4. **Redis** - быстрая БД для промежуточной записи результатов игры.

Пункты 2,3,4 - выбор на мой вкус, есть аналоги технологий и другие варианты реализации.

Если по-гуглите по этим темам - найдёте много примеров с отдалённо похожим функционалом.

Задача далеко не самая банальная.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!